# Laravel 5.4 mongodb passport access token Unauthenticated

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I've built an example Laravel project using mongodb ([Jenssegers Mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)) and I use passport in Laravel 5.4 follow [by this document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport).

Everything work fine until I took an access token to Postman for test, now take a look at my `api.php` route

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

In postman, I setup two headers that are `Accept: application/json` and `Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN` and I'm very sure that my access token is not the copy missing fault but still getting error.

```
{
    "error": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

**Things I've tried**

I have overwrite default `id` field in model `User.php`

```
use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

protected $collection = 'users';
protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'name'];
protected $primaryKey = '_id';
```

I also modify the token expiration time in `AuthserviceProvider.php` like so

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Passport::routes();
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addYears(20));//You can also use addDays(10)
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addYears(20));//You can also use addDays(10)
    Passport::pruneRevokedTokens(); //basic garbage collector

    Passport::tokensCan([
        'conference' => 'Access your conference information'
    ]);
}
```

And some other ways but still not work.

**UPDATE for debug infomation**

When I add `try catch` in to `public/index.php`, an error apperead

```
League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException: The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. in /data/www/public_html/xxxx/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:165
Stack trace:
#0 /data/www/public_html/xxxx/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/AuthorizationValidators/BearerTokenValidator.php(66): League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::accessDenied('Access token ha...')
#1 /data/www/public_html/xxxx/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/ResourceServer.php(82): League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationValidators\BearerTokenValidator->validateAuthorization(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest))
......
```

When I check file `vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\AuthorizationValidators\BearerTokenValidator.php` at `line 66`. Seems my access token has been revoked, but in my database `revoked` column still false, and this access token is brand new, I just created in few minutes ago.

```
if ($this->accessTokenRepository->isAccessTokenRevoked($token->getClaim('jti'))) {
    throw OAuthServerException::accessDenied('Access token has been revoked');
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few hours of digging deep in to `vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\AuthorizationValidators\BearerTokenValidator.php` I was found a solution.

The problem is in file `vendor\laravel\passport\src\TokenRepository.php` at function `public function find($id)` line 27

```
public function find($id)
{
    return Token::find($id);
}
```

Because I use Mobodb and this function is use `use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model` and it search for `_id` instead of `id`. So, just need to make change find function like this.

```
public function find($id)
{
    return Token::where('id', $id)->first();
}
```

Although modify vendor file is not recommend, but in this case I have to do that, hopefully in next version, author of Laravel passport will release a passport support mongoDB.

Hope this help someone.

Comment: UPDATE: Looks like this change has been made as part of the core in version 7: https://github.com/laravel/passport/commit/47eaf7221411ba337faa518e20fdfaf9d9548cbf#diff-06bd1a6d5154d7fdbeeef72178ba6f5aR29